# lsyncd: Can't run sync with rsync chown option

Tags: lsyncd

Whats incorrect about this syntax? it wont let me run the sync..

```
settings = {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
},
sync {
    default.rsync,
    source = "/home/path1",
    target = "/home/path2",
    delay     = 15, 
    rsync     = {
        chown = webdev:webdev
    }
}
```

Comment: Running in to same problem. In my case its `chown = "apache:apache"`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both of these as well. With "" and without.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
rsync     = {
    owner = true,
    group = true,
    chown = "webdev:webdev"
}
```